# How do i exclude IP addresses from Get-NETTCPConnection when outputting it in a list?

Tags: powershell

I want to exclude certain IP address e.g 0.0.0.0 from my output, any suggestions on how to do that?
Here is my script so far:

```
Function Get-NetConnections {

    $NetInfo = Get-NetTCPConnection | Select-Object

    PSCustomObject]@{
        LocalPort = $NetInfo.LocalPort
        RemotePort = $NetInfo.RemotePort
        ConnectionState = $NetInfo.State
        OwningProcess = $NetInfo.OwningProcess 
        }        
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In the code, `Select-Object` isn't doing anything. If you want to filter the first choice is usually `Where-Object`.  Modifying your function might look something like below.

```
Function Get-NetConnections 
{
    Param(
        [Parameter( Mandatory = $false, Position = 0 )]
        [String[]]$ExcludedIPs
    ) # End Param block...

    $NetInfo = 
    Get-NetTCPConnection | 
    Where-Object{ $_.RemoteAddress -notin $ExcludedIPs }

    PSCustomObject]@{
        LocalPort       = $NetInfo.LocalPort
        RemotePort      = $NetInfo.RemotePort
        ConnectionState = $NetInfo.State
        OwningProcess   = $NetInfo.OwningProcess 
        }        

} # End Function Get-NetConnections
```

In this case I added a parameter for the excluded IPs, hardcoding or assigning the excluded IPs as a default argument to the parameter may also be options.  Perhaps that depends on how reusable you want your code to be. Is it a one-off or will be used all the time with different parameters etc.?

I also assumed it was the remote address you were interested in filtering out.  However, the above concepts should work regardless, you can modify as needed.

One final point. You may want to type the parameter differently which would give you a form of parameter validation. That might look something like:

```
Function Get-NetConnections 
{
    Param(
        [Parameter( Mandatory = $false, Position = 0 )]
        [System.Net.IPAddress[]]$ExcludedIPs
    ) # End Param block...

    $NetInfo = 
    Get-NetTCPConnection | 
    Where-Object{ $_.RemoteAddress -notin $ExcludedIPs }

    PSCustomObject]@{
        LocalPort       = $NetInfo.LocalPort
        RemotePort      = $NetInfo.RemotePort
        ConnectionState = $NetInfo.State
        OwningProcess   = $NetInfo.OwningProcess 
        }        

} # End Function Get-NetConnections
```

Basic tests I did show PowerShell type conversion under the hood still allows the `Where{}` clause to function normally.